# Typescript: Private key in public object

Tags: typescript, class, object, private, public

Is there a way to add a private key in a public object ?

```
export class user {
    public details: {
        lastname: string,
        firstname: string,
        username: string
    }
}
```

I would like username not to be able to be set outside a method in the class.
Example, something like that :

```
export class user {
    public details: {
        lastname: string,
        firstname: string,
        private _username: string
    }

    public setUsername() {
        this.details._username = `${lastname} ${firstname}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: "able to be set", sounds like you want it to be *`readonly`*, not *`private`*.  Or do you mean that you don't want people outside the class to be able to *read* `username` either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want this (and if you really want `private`-like behavior as opposed to just `readonly`), but I'd suggest in such cases that you put your classes into a module where you only export the intended public-facing types.  Something like the following:

```
namespace Library {
  export interface Details {
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
  }
  interface PrivateDetails extends Details {
    username: string;
  }
  class PrivateUser {
    details: PrivateDetails;
    constructor(lastname: string, firstname: string) {
      this.details = { lastname, firstname, username: "" };
      this.setUsername(); // I guess?
    }
    setUsername() {
      this.details.username = `${this.details.lastname} ${
        this.details.firstname
      }`;
    }
  }
  export type User = Omit<PrivateUser, "details"> & {
    details: Details;
  };
  export const User: new (
    ...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof PrivateUser>
  ) => User = PrivateUser;
}
```

So inside the library there is a `PrivateUser` class and a `PrivateDetails` type, where the `details` property of `PrivateUser` is a `PrivateDetails`.  These types and values are not exported.  What we export are a `User` class* and a `Details` type, where the `details` property of `User` is a `Details`.  (*Note that we are actually exporting a `type` and a `const`, both named `User`.  The `type` corresponds to the type of a `User` instance and the `const` is the constructor.  A `class` definition does this automatically, but we have to do it in two lines here).

Okay, let's use it:

```
import User = Library.User;
const u = new User("Turing", "Alan");
console.log(u.details.firstname); // Turing
console.log(u.details.lastname); // Alan
console.log(u.details.username); // error!
// Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Details'.
// of course, at runtime, it still outputs "Turing Alan", just like a private property does
u.details.lastname = "Alda";
u.setUsername(); // okay
console.log(u.details.username); // still compiler error, outputs "Alda Alan" at runtime
```

This works how I think you want.  From the inside `Library`, the `PrivateUser` class has full access to its `details.username` property.  But from outside, the exposed `User` class does not.  Meaning that you'll get a compiler error if you try to use it.  Of course at runtime the access will succeed, but `private` properties work that way also, so I assume that's okay.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAZAlgIwE4iwTyQG8BYAKCSQgA8YB7LAFyTWAYiwDMFkARCBkGgA2UImQoUhIKA1CQAXEhlYWAcwDc4iRzRYZciIuVrN5JAF8tLNp25IACioBuINnwHDR1NsAAmo90ERMTMKAFcodgMjBhVgDS1LM3gpKFFHNBc2AFVIrBCJJF9+IKhFDKyIQM9TQvhaYGUw+AZ6AApU2XBDJVi1ABokHT0uhV641QBKAsKkBgALNCgAOmKPYIBeIiROg0Hh-W7BiKjuxQAic4ta2YWl5ciGXNPINsn1JAB6T6QASSRVGFoFAAPxaChJQqPZ5YAxvGaFO4rNalZYnWHdJBbAAGABJCEjViVPMtdt1zEh8eDbotkcSRMsDqMINSIdibhDEloGHgYMgYVikAB5MBoBgAHgqrggMMG5xRnnOAD4kAAyBFFellJDVEQ3cw3ah0RhIeqNJgwxTACAAdyQbWpyyduFU2oAwg0mi16PZcN0bFBxTy+bQOA5nNKYUqtNMNiqBVspTk8qYkmQ0GBjRa8oL0NhcHhljDTGaZEgwoLrXaYW1zgAVMITc5ygCCUmA53eZFLtCEEFJtFUbTCRPWKyZBneXx+DYm3c9vf7QkHw9HqLJkCn3yQbZAwHnjUXA6HI4VDPRk4+2-YWHoAEIyNvHLQ+YwCAByC-dd9FWjQJDALQTDUEsTANHMvLIO+upQO+yyPj8oamrQjaRIMrhIFgYSsBmECDGKvTCEISAoQwMBhAwoj1o2ag7u2zZIAAVhETBCGgADWyAgEgMARmwPG3q+PK-tAZCnlqpLSMygrnG2vggOcpgjtCeRwluiHsSAeAHlAR7Liea4kl+m5Xj8MhEchmbCOwlBYLeWCDKR5GUUgslCPJdF7lcGFYThkBkEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
export class user {

    public lastname: string,
    public firstname: string,
    private _username: string

    public setUsername() {
        this._username = `${this.lastname} ${this.firstname}`;
    }
}
```